# How the Diagnostic Trouble Code(DTC) data is defined in the ECU?

Tags: protocols, can-bus, diagnostics, automotive

When a diagnostic tool is connected to the server it gets the the **DTC**.

I want to know how the **DTC** data is defined and stored in the ECU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTC codes are usually defined as 2-byte or 3-byte values.

A common representation following [ISO 15031-6](https://www.iso.org/standard/66369.html)/[SAE J2012](https://www.sae.org/standards/content/j2012_201303/) is as five-character alphanumeric code (ie. `P0001`) with the optional low-byte appended as hexadecimal value (ie. `P0001-00`). The first letter being either: **P** for **Powertrain** (`00b`, highest bits on highest byte), **C** for **Chassis** (`01b`), **B** for **Body** (`10b`) or **U** for **Network** related DTCs (`11b`). ie.

`P0001` (Fuel Volume Regulator Control Circuit/Open) would be represented as bytes: `0x00 0x01`

`P0A01` (Range/Performance) would be represented as bytes: `0x0A 0x01`

`C0001` (TCS Control Channel A Valve 1) would be represented as bytes: `0x40 0x01`

The DTCs are stored as their respective byte representation in Non-volatile memory (NvM) of the ECU, so that it can be retrieved even if the ECU has been power cycled. Along with the DTC additional information will be stored, i.e. Freeze frame/environmental data, DTC status mask (pendingDTC/confirmedDTC/...), counter (aging/debouncing), time of first occurence, etc.